# Neo4J Cypher Total match while pagination

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query the database for some matches using the SKIP and LIMIT, but at the same time get the total matches found, but looks like its not really possible. below is the query i am trying

```
MATCH (city:City)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-()<-[r:HAS_ADDRESS]-(user:Person) 
RETURN user AS EMPLOYEE, Count(user) AS TOTAL 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

but I am getting a result different from what I expected... I expected the total to be 2, but i see 1 & 3. is it possible to have a total count returned from the query without making multiple query calls ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

User 610 maybe has three different addresses in the same city or for some othe reason it's matched three times; to get the number of distinct users you should use DISTINCT:

```
MATCH (city:City)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-()<-[r:HAS_ADDRESS]-(user:Person) 
RETURN user AS EMPLOYEE, Count(distinct user) AS TOTAL 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Actually its not working correctly, as it returns total count as 1. Looks like its returning how many times a user is present in the result set. I was expecting to get a total numbers of users matched, not just what is result set.

Comment: Just remove the `user AS EMPLOYEE, ` from the return clause.

Comment: Sorry does not help, i still get (Node 621) -> 1 & (Node 610) -> 1